# What is the minimum number of test cases for edge and condition coverage in this example?

Tags: java, c, code-coverage, test-coverage

The solution for this problem in my textbook is that the minimum number of test cases is 3. However, I can't go below 4 for the full edge and condition coverage.

```
int x=0;
int k=10;
while (x<=10 && z>0) {
   if (z<=y && k>=x)
      y=y-z;
   k--;
   if (y>0) x++;
   else break;
}
```

My solution would be something like this: `{z=1, y=0},{z=-1, y=0},{z=1, y=10},{z=1, y=3}`. Which of these (if any) is redundant?
What is the three test cases combination that solve this problem? Or is there an error in my textbook?

Comment: Hmmm,  Trying to achieve the absolute minimum test cases is a questionable goal.  To do so, one needs to assume much about code and that leads to problems as code ages.   I suppose this is just an exercise.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica even thinking about it as "just an exercise", I can't understand how with only 3 test cases one can test the true and false of all the sub-condition.

Comment: Could try all `z` [-10 ...10] and `y` [-10  ... 10], see  the results of `x, k`.  Maybe only 3 sets?

Answer (score 0):

Curious function.

As seen below, with just looking as `x`, there are a number of interesting regions that each deserve a test vector.

I disagree that "minimum number of test cases is 3."

```
struct kx {
  int k, x;
};

struct kx foo(int z, int y) {
  int x = 0;
  int k = 10;
  while (x <= 10 && z > 0) {
    if (z <= y && k >= x)
      y = y - z;
    k--;
    if (y > 0)
      x++;
    else
      break;
  }
  struct kx r = {k, x};
  return r;
}

int main(void) {
  for (int z = -2; z <= 12; z++) {
    for (int y = -2; y <= 20; y++) {
      struct kx newest = foo(z, y);
      printf(" %2d", newest.x);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Output

```
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  1  2  3  4  5 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
  0  0  0 11  0 11  1 11  2 11  3 11  4 11  5 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
  0  0  0 11 11  0 11 11  1 11 11  2 11 11  3 11 11  4 11 11  5 11 11
  0  0  0 11 11 11  0 11 11 11  1 11 11 11  2 11 11 11  3 11 11 11  4
  0  0  0 11 11 11 11  0 11 11 11 11  1 11 11 11 11  2 11 11 11 11  3
  0  0  0 11 11 11 11 11  0 11 11 11 11 11  1 11 11 11 11 11  2 11 11
  0  0  0 11 11 11 11 11 11  0 11 11 11 11 11 11  1 11 11 11 11 11 11
  0  0  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  1 11 11 11 11
  0  0  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  1 11 11
  0  0  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  1
  0  0  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
  0  0  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11  0 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum number of test cases to achieve 100% condition coverage is indeed 3.

Here are the test cases: `{z=10,y=1},{z=1,y=1},{z=1,y=10}`

To achieve full condition coverage, each of the Boolean expression in a condition must have been evaluated to each `true` and `false` respectively.

For    `if (z<=y && k>=x)` condition

```
z<=y : true
k>=x: true

z<=y : true
k>=x: false

z<=y : false
k>=x: false

z<=y : false
k>=x: true
```

For `if(y>0)` condition

```
y>0: true

y>0:false
```

Note that since there is a while loop with modification of variable values, there can be multiple Boolean expressions covered in just a test case.

The first test case `{z=10,y=1}` covers

```
z<=y : false
k>=x: false

z<=y : false
k>=x: true

y>0: true
```

The second test case `{z=1,y=1}` covers

```
z<=y : true
k>=x: true

y>0:false
```

The third test case `{z=1,y=10}` covers the remaining Boolean expression

```
z<=y : true
k>=x: false
```

With that every Boolean expression in every condition in the code is covered, therefore ensuring 100% condition coverage

You can print to console the Boolean values of the expression required just before the if statements to ensure every Boolean expression in a condition is evaluated to `true` and `false` respectively.

```
int x=0;
int k=10;
while (x<=10 && z>0) {
   System.out.println((z<=y),(k>=x))
   if (z<=y && k>=x)
      y=y-z;
   k--;
   System.out.println((y>0))
   if (y>0) x++;
   else break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need 3 test cases, but some of the answers did not consider the conditions in the while loop: you need to cover the case when z>0 is false (as you did).
So two test cases for covering edge and  conditions in the body of the while, e.g.:

(1,0) covering the  conditions z<=y false and y<0 false, together with the edge "false" of the first "if";

(1,10) covering in the first 5 iterations the conditions z<=y true, k>=x true,  and y>0 false, together with the edge true of the first if; in the following iterations this covers also  the remaining condition k>=x  false. No need to cover again z<=y false since it was already covered by the first test case!

Just add (-1,any) to cover the missing condition z>0 false.

The case (1,3) of OP is not necessary.